# Bluetooth was working but just stopped?

Tags: ubuntu, bluetooth, bluez

I recently upgraded to the latest FGLRX driver on my MacBook Pro and I noticed that Bluetooth was having some issues afterward. I tried reinstalling bluetooth and bluez, but it didn't seem to fix things. Before the FGLRX upgrade, it was working just fine. Unfortunately, it's a really big hassle to downgrade from FGLRX, and I don't have the time to spend in getting it back to 11.12.

I do have `etckeeper` installed and I've checked out the revision before I did any changes, restarted bluetooth, and it's still giving me the same error in syslog when I try to connect my keyboard:

```
$ tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep "blue"
Jan 30 11:56:31 work-macbook bluetoothd[9457]: Refusing input device connect: No such file or directory (2)
Jan 30 11:56:31 work-macbook bluetoothd[9457]: Refusing input device connect: No such file or directory (2)
```

I have no idea what file it's looking for.

Is there a way for me to either:

1. Revert all of my changes and just get Bluetooth working again.
2. Enable Bluez logging to be able to see what it's unable to find?

This is super weird. Can anyone help me debug this?